# Lighting Components: Dynamically Call Aura Method

Tags: lightning, javascript-controller

Is it possible for a lightning component to make a call to the method in another component by using the name of its `aura:method` dynamically?  Or can it only be hardcoded?

e.g

Child component:

```
<aura:method name="myMethod" action="{!c.myMethod}"/>
```

Parent component hard coded:

```
var childCmp = component.find('childCmp');
childCmp.myMethod();
```

I want do to something like this:

```
var methodName = 'myMethod' ;
var childCmp = component.find('childCmp');
childCmp.methodName();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, you can dynamically call aura method accessing a function through the **bracket notation** `[]`:

```
var methodName = 'myMethod' ;
var childCmp = component.find('childCmp');
childCmp[methodName]();
```